# How do I trigger a shortcut automation when disconnecting from Wi-Fi?

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

I'd like to create a shortcut that does something whenever I disconnect from Wi-Fi. How do I do this?

I know I can go to Shortcuts > Automation > Create Personal Automation > Wi-Fi, but this will only trigger when a network is joined, not when one is disconnected.

How do I trigger an automation when a network is joined?

---

The specific shortcut I'd like to do is:

1. ✅ Enable Airplane mode when Wi-Fi network is joined. -- This is already done as it was simple to implement.
2. ❌ Disable Airplane mode when Wi-Fi network is disconnected. -- This is the one I'm having trouble with.

Comment: On macOS I would trap or leverage the disconnect notification of this awesome app. https://www.adriangranados.com/apps/wifisignal iOS is going to be tricky unless Apple has an API and I would doubt that exists